# Change PostgreSQL Default ID sequence in Rails create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have an sql dump file which I imported to my database. All of the records from this sql dump has id's starting from 900 to 2500.

So the problem is that If I will create new record from my rails app, it will get automatic id = 1, the next will get 2,3,4 etc. I guess when I i will create my 900s records, I will get an error, since id=900 already exists.

Note: I cant change my id's to start from 1 in my sql dump file, since another table references it by id.

Is there any solution?

I use PostgreSQL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails gets the id that it uses from the database, in the case of postgres there are corresponding sequences for each table's `id` field, so in order to get Rails to skip over that block of `id`s you just need to update the corresponding sequence:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE plural_table_name_id_seq RESTART WITH 2501;
```

You could put that into a Rails migration if you liked, or just run it on your databases.